# Recalculate date

Tags: mysql

I  am doing a cronjob that should check the database for new Users, the cronjob runs every day at lunch.

I want to get an email with all users created between YESTERDAY after Lunch and TODAY Lunch, so the last 24 hrs.

How can I do it?

Like

```
WHERE userCreationDate WITHIN LAST 24 HRS
```

?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) and [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to specify the date then specify your interval.

```
where userCreationDate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```